# How can I align this tabular so that true on the right of page?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I want to align this tabular so that it is true on the right of page. I tried

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabular}{ c c }
\textbf{Long text Long text Long text  } & \hspace{0.5cm} \textbf{Subject Subject}  \\
\textbf{Long text Long text  }  & \hspace{0.5cm} \textbf{Year 2013 - 2014} \\
& \hspace{0.5cm}  \textbf{Mathematica}  \\
&\hspace{0.5cm} (\emph{\textit{Time}: \textbf{90 minutes}})\\ 
& \hspace{0.5cm}  \rule{1.7in}{1pt}
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]
How can I align it?

I changed `\hspace{0.5cm}` to `\hspace{1cm}` and I got
[image]

Comment: How about using `\hspace{\fill}` in front of the `tabular` environment?  Also, not sure what you're trying to achieve with the `flushleft` environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if I've interpreted your write-up correctly, but I'm assuming you want the material in the second column of the table to be typeset hard against the right-hand edge of the textblock. If this is the correct interpretation, your objective may be achieved by using a `tabular*` environment. Its width should be set to `\textwidth`, and the directive `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` is inserted to maximize the intercolumn whitespace to push the right-hand column to the right-hand edge of the textblock. (This directive also makes it unnecessary to provide explicit `\hspace` statements.) Finally, insert `@{}` to eliminate whitespace to the left of the first column and to the right of the second column.

The instruction `\hrule` in the following MWE is provided just to illustrate the width of the text block.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{} c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} c @{}}
\textbf{Long text Long text Long text} & \textbf{Subject Subject}  \\
\textbf{Long text Long text}  & \textbf{Year 2013--2014} \\
& \textbf{Mathematica}  \\
& (\emph{\textit{Time}: \textbf{90 minutes}})\\ 
& \rule{1.7in}{1pt}
\end{tabular*}
\medskip
\hrule  % just to illustrate width of text block
\end{document}
```

Comment: You alined on the right. Can you format right block like my picture (on the right)?

Comment: @minthao_2011 - Sure: just replace the `r` alignment specifier for the second column with `c`. Give me a minute to change the MWE and image.

Answer (score 3):

I would use two `tabular` environments, that make for easier input: the two blocks are separated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft} % avoids indentation and has some space after it
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt} % thicker rule
\makebox[\textwidth][s]{%
  \bfseries % global font for this part
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  Long text Long text Long text\\
  Long text Long text
  \end{tabular}\hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  Subject Subject \\
  Year 2013--2014 \\
  Mathematics \\
  \itshape\textmd{Time}: 90 minutes \\[3pt]
  \hline
  \end{tabular}%
}
\end{flushleft}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Pay attention to spurious spaces; I put `%` where one would be produced.

[image]